# AES 128 and Firefox block

Tags: firefox, encryption, video-streaming

I have a website that shows videos with HLS streaming encrypted with AES 128. I found that they are downloadable with Firefox video Downlodhelper. I don´t want the videos to be downloaded, so i´m looking for a way to make the website pages where i show the videos nor available for Firefox. Anyone knows a way to prevent Firefox from browsing specific pages on a website?....
thanks

Comment: They will always be downloadable via something. Like wget or curl. From the servers perspective, there is no different between downloading and streaming.

Comment: You may check the Agent header, however - technically it won't prevent downloading the key anyway